# Adding shadow below TabBar - Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have an actionbar and tab bar. I removed shadow below actionbar with

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Though, I want to add shadow under tab bar. I'm using SlidingTabLayout. My tab TextView:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
android:textColor="@color/tab_color"
android:gravity="center"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:singleLine="true" />
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 21):

jmols answer results in a different shadow than what Google apps (e.g. Play Newsstand) use. This is my method, which results in the shadow looking exactly the same as Play Newsstand:

[image]

Create a drawable called `shadow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#33000000"
        android:angle="90">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

Then, set that shadow to your content layout, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Your views here -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Placed underneath your toolbar/action bar, this will look exactly the same as the implementation in Play Newsstand and Play Store.

Comment: This worked great for me, whereas setElevation, setZ or setTranslationZ only caused the tabs to get darker without actual shadow.

Comment: This is the simplest and most useful solution out there. Brilliant

Answer (score 3):

Shadows are currently only supported on Api level 21 (as they are rendered in real time) and are not provided by the support library unfortunately.

Hence you will have to mimic the shadows yourself using a custom drawable on api levels < 21.
The easiest way to do this is:

- take the [shadow 9-patch](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/dfaf8b83ad1b3e7c8d1af0b08d59caf4223e0b95/android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/bottom_shadow.9.png) from the Google IO app.
- set that shadow to your main content layout, for example:

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
          android:title="@string/toolbar_title"
          android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"/>

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/fl_fragment_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/tb_toolbar"
          android:foreground="@drawable/bottom_shadow"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Note: the only notable exception to this is CardView, this one does cast its own shadow on older api levels.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474766/how-to-show-the-shadow-of-the-actionbartoolbar-of-the-support-library-on-all-an) for more information.

Comment: If the framelayout contains some child views, it it probably better to use the shadow  drawable as its **foreground**. That way it will be drawn always over them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll change that! :)

Comment: This works, albeit I cant get content to scroll under the shadow. It is not so transparent at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Material Design, to add a shadow to a view you need to specify the `android:elevation` attribute in your layout or call `myView.setElevation()` method in your code. You can have more on defining shadows with material design in the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

Comment: My minSdk is 18. Is there a way of using this attribute with support library?

Comment: elevation is a correct answer but it just supports greater sdk21

Answer (score 0):

Just add elevation to your `Tablayout` (0dp - 25dp). Read the material design [guidelines](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html) for more information about elevation.

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

**Below example:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/splashGreenTop"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="10dp" />
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" 
    android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

Same question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675791/how-to-add-bottom-shadow-to-tab-layout-or-toolbar-in-android)

be aware, if you have the following line in the manifest then shadows wont show:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

And another link to follow: [Link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)