# How to add bottom shadow to tab layout or Toolbar in android

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, shadow, android-elevation

Hi i need add shadow under my tab layout (like in skype).

[image: shadow_skype]

My activity xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/splashGreenTop"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i add `android:elevation="10dp"` to Tablayout, shadow was added bottom and top .. I need just bottom. See image...

[image]

How can i do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572048/elevation-on-android-lollipop-not-working

Comment: I have a issue like yours.. do you have solve the problem ?
Can you read my question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174641/how-can-i-show-the-shadow-only-on-the-bottom-side-of-the-tablayout

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add elevation to your `Tablayout` (0dp - 25dp). Read the [material design](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html) guidelines for more information about elevation.

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

**EDIT:**
add it to both your tablayout and toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/splashGreenTop"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="10dp" />
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" 
    android:elevation="10dp"/>
```

Comment: @puko as i said add the elevation to your `ToolBar` too

Comment: @puko also you can specify the level of the shadow by the elevation value. The value of the skype screenshot elevation is probably 4-8dp. Read the material design guide that i suggested, its very helpful!

Comment: why toolbar and tablayout have different background? splashGreenTop & colorPrimary ?

Comment: this answer doesn't make sense, both toolbar and tablayout will have shadow, there should not be any shadow between toolbar and tablayout

Comment: @user924 It does make sense because elevation doesn't add the shadow, it elevates the view (think of it as z-index). The ambient and point lightning make the shadow appear. If both views have the same elevation then there will be no shadow between them.

Answer (score 13):

> This is a  Great option to add shadow below Toolbar

Add a `view` below the `tablayout` of your desired `layout`

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/splashGreenTop"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

       <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then create a `xml` in  drawable like this
**@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="#88333333"
    android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

Change the `startcolor` and `endcolor` as u want to apply

Answer (score 5):

You can add TabLayout as a child in AppBarLayout which has a shadow by default or you can specify the shadow depth by **app:elevation="xdp"**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="xdp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        ...
        />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
        ...
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: full example with toolbar support then, I don't think it will work

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a simple View between TabLayout and Toolbar. Set background for that View as gradient which mimics shadow.

**Shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
        android:startColor="#20000000"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="90">
  </gradient>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a quite simple solution:
Just put the Toolbar and the TabLayout inside of an AppBarLayout. 
For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This works perfectly for me and it's the common way to combine the App-/Toolbar and the TabLayout.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why this answer has many votes when it says to set elevation for both toolbar and tablayout https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675808/7767664

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line and it will work.

```
   android:elevation="5dp"
```

See full code:

```
   <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayoutSave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#1d1d1f"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#1d1d1f"
    app:tabTextColor="#888888" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add elevation into your `Tablayout`. [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html)

```
android:elevation="15dp"
```

Answer (score -3):

Use `app:elevation="0dp"` to remove the shadow.