# How can we set elevation or shadow at bottom for Tablayout?

Tags: android, material-design

I have a tablayout with viewpager in a fragment. Now I want to set bottom shadow to the tablayout. I searched regarding this and tried using android:elevation value but it doesn't show any shadow to the tablayout.
I also setting android:clipChildren="false" and android:clipToPadding="false" and margin bottom value. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add bottom shadow to tab layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675791/how-to-add-bottom-shadow-to-tab-layout)

Answer (score 0):

If your minimum api version is 21 or more then use below

```
android:elevation="6dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's from code you can use:

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(yourView,elevationFloat)
```