# Is there any way to add custom shadow to Android Tab Item?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablayout, android-tabs, android-elevation

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_baground"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFF"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="20dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="20dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="Item 1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:text="Item 2"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

I get the following visual effect on using the above code.

[image]

But I need some shadow for the each item used in tab layout. I tried using elevation in tab item but it's not working.

Comment: try using custom way to create shadow in TabView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675979/9908240

Comment: I need shadow for the tab item. For tab layout, it's working

Comment: As per TabItem documentation we can setBackground. More information https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabItem

Comment: Tried that, but failed